# set property grid's headers visible

Tags: javascript, extjs, propertygrid

I know that `hideHeaders: true` hides the property grid's headers (names, values).

Now, **if I want to make the headers visible from outside, how I can achieve that?**

Example:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', 
{
    id: 'grid',
    hideHeaders: true   
});

// I get/create a source here
grid.setSource(data);

// now, since my grid is full, I want to show the headers
// tried this but did not work :/
grid.add({hideHeaders: false});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to do that built into the framework, but you could probably hack your way to the solution...

On your grid, add a listener to hide the headers:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(grid) {
        grid.headerCt.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Then, when you're ready to show the headers again:

```
grid.headerCt.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Seems good solution, you just need to start the grid with `hideHeadrs: false` for it to work properly.

Comment: @AmitAviv If I do not write `hideHeaders: true`, it will automatically understand as `false`

Comment: Sure, just wanted to make it explicit, because in your code you hade it set to true.